# when i run command sh.enableSharding("test_db") , i get the error

Tags: mongodb

```
> when i run the command sh.enableSharding("test_db") , i get the error
```

> "errmsg" : "Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr"

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory. You are not connecting to an instance with sharding enabled. Read [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) carefully.

Comment: can you please tell ,  where i have to make changes

Comment: I did. [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/). **Read** the instructions there.

Comment: You should hit this command on mongos server after all the shard servers are up and connected.Remember your config server should be running